# search recursive files with type of data that ended with specific extension in order to delete the files

Tags: linux, bash, shell, file, find

We want to search and delete the `data` files that ended with extension of `.pppd`

We can search the files as

```
find  $path -type f -name '*.pppd' -delete
```

but how to tell to `find` command to filter only the `data` files?

Example how to verify if file is data  ( by `file` command )

```
file /data/file.pppd
/data/file.pppd: data
```

file command from manual page

```
NAME
     file — determine file type

SYNOPSIS
     file [-bchiklLNnprsvz0] [--apple] [--mime-encoding] [--mime-type] [-e testname] [-F separator] [-f namefile] [-m magicfiles] file ...
     file -C [-m magicfiles]
     file [--help]
```

Comment: Isn't there an easier way to distinguish *data* files? `file` takes a lot of time

Comment: so you have `.pppd` files that aren't data files? How did that happen!? ;-) . Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to launch a shell:

```
find "${path}" \
    -type f \
    -name '*.pppd' \
    -exec bash -c 'test "$(file "${1}"|awk -F: "{print \$NF}")" = "data"' -- {} \; \
    -print
```

Comment: launching bash for every single file is not a good idea. sh is usually a link to a lighter shell, I recommend using it; and more importantly, using bulk-exec (`-exec ... {} +`) with a loop in the shell code you can save a lot of time.

Comment: Sure, and a good point. Let me just say that as long as performance isn't a problem, I would just keep it simple. I mean in most to all realistic use cases it shouldn't make any recognizable difference.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `find` command with the `exec` option to launch an explicit subshell that runs a shell loop to compare the output type.

```
find "$path" -type f \
             -name '*.pppd' \
             -exec bash -c 'for f; do [[ $(file -b "$f") = "data" ]] && echo "$f"  ; done' _ {} +
```

This [Unix.SE answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/389706/112235) beautifully explains how the `-exec bash -c` option works with the `find` command. To briefly explain how it works, the result of `find` command based on the filter conditions ( `-name`, `-type` and `-path` ) are passed as positional arguments to the loop run under `exec bash -c '..'`. The loop iterates over the argument list ( `for f` is analogous to `for f in "$@"` ) and prints only the files whose type is `data`. Instead of parsing the result of `file`, use `file -b` to get the type directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this. you can change **empty** regex for a valid Bash regex like for instance **^data** and the **txt** extension for what you want to search for :

```
#!/bin/bash

read -a files <<< $(find  . -type f -name '*.pppd' )
for file in "${files[@]}"
do
    [[ "$(file -b $file )" =~ ^empty ]] && echo $file
done
```

If you want to delete the file :

```
[[ "$(file -b $file )" =~ ^empty ]] || rm "$file"
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: What if some file names contain spaces?

Comment: the important thing is files ended with .pppd ,and file type is data

Comment: @Judy You can simply do whatever you want if the test is successful. Replace the echo with something else as I shown an example.

Comment: @oguzismail If it were my server files would not contain spaces to begin with. Anyway you can sanitize the file naming with **tr** first and remove characters outside of [a-zA-Z0-9_] range

Comment: Did you try what you just said? :D

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice